# Marshmallow limiting records in nested schema

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Will oversimplify a bit but hope the issue is clear thru this example:

I am using mysql with sqlalchemy ORM. Let's say I have a table called 'cellphoneTable' and another called "billTable".  There is a 1-many relationship from cellphone to bills. Using Marshmallow, I have the following and IT WORKS:

```
class cellphoneSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    number = fields.Str()     
    bills = fields.nested('billSchema', many=True)

class billSchema(Schema):
   <nothing special here: assume some Ints Floats Dates and Strings>
```

Now when I want to dump my cellphone data with bills:

```
c1 = <get a cellphone record via session.query(cellphoneTable).get(c_id)...>
cs = cellphoneSchema()
return cs.dump(c1).data
```

As stated above, this works. I get the cellphone data and all associated bills for that c_id.

HOWEVER, I only want to get, for example, last 12 months of bills (or last 3 or some such limit).

What's the best way to constrain Marshmallow nested query to limit the "number of rows", without having to write the query myself, and then "join" the two results to jsonify and return -- note that I do such queries on many tables all over in my application, so hoping to avoid code bloat and handcrafting a lot of this.

Does Marshmallow support this? Any ideas? Thru Decorators or ???? though most of what I have read operates on individual object (like pre_load or post_load). Plus I don't want to get all rows and then throw away most of what I don't need and there's quite a bit of what I don't need (note: we are talking about retrieving tens of rows from possibly hundreds).

Comment: I think that you have to do this on query, the concept of the marshamallow is just serialize/deserialize objects passed to him. Ortherwise you have to use pre_load/post_load